# Can't get Audio CD Extractor to open when I insert a CD

Tags: 11.10, banshee, cd, autostart

When I insert a CD I want Audio CD Extractor to open. Right now Banshee opens.
I've gone to System Settings, Removable Media and I have chosen Audio CD Extractor for how CD Audio media should be handled to no effect.
I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.
Thank you for your help.
[image: Removable Media System Settings]